# Display help message for adb logcat?

Tags: android, logcat

Is there a help switch available for adb logcat?

There is an online document like http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html, but it is also interesting to know if it is also there in command line itself too or not, this might comes in handy when we do not have internet connection.

I have tried adb logcat with **-?, /?, --help,** (on Windows) but with no help message. **adb help** command also does not explain how to use switches in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you got android SDK package with documents downloaded (from bundle or SDK manager), you can access offline version at its /sdk folder:

For example, for **logcat** help:

> SDKPATH/sdk/docs/tools/help/logcat.html

Still, cannot find a way to displaying help message in command line application itself though.